Why do I get "This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly"
I'm using Python and PyCharm on Windows 11.  I recently upgraded from Python 3.12 to Python 3.13.  When running in PyCharm, I now get the error
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Users/kbens/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/Earnie/.venv/lib/tcl8.6} {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/Earnie/lib/tcl8.6} {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/Earnie/.venv/library} {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/Earnie/library} {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/Earnie/tcl8.6.14/library} {C:/Users/kbens/OneDrive/Earnie TradeBot/Code/tcl8.6.14/library}

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Based on other posts I've seen, I installed the latest Tcl.  It made no difference.

How did you upgrade from Python 3.12 to Python 3.13?

I downloaded 3.13 from python.org.  I ended up with 3.13 and 3.12 (looking at installed apps.  So I uninstalled 3.12.  I haven't tried unistalling 3.13, ensuring everything is uninstalled and then reinstalling 3.13.

I just tried a clean install.  It didn't help.

Are you using a virtual environment? If not, start there: first create a virtual environment, then activate it, then install all your dependencies.

So I'm a bit of a newbie so please bear with me.  I'm using PyCharm.  I had Python 3.12 working with PyCharm.  When I upgraded to Python 3.13 I started getting the error.

I think the answer to the virtual environment question is no.

I programming in Windows only.  What is the advantage of a virtual environment?

I think, your package destionation is wrong. You use onedrive, and need to move correct directory.

Thanks.  "Correct directory", what does that mean?

The message means that the Tcl runtime couldn't find a file it loads as part of its bootstrapping. It's broken. Several reasons possible why, but it's probably related to environment variables set (incorrectly) by Python. In Tcl 9.0 we can bind the scripts into the DLL and get away from this mess.

It looks like it will be fixed.

Having .venv in your paths means that a virtual environment may be present. It's common name for the virtual environment directory. PyCharm activates the virtual environment, if it exists, by default.

From above comments i get this idea, please try running code in python from cmd directly using python something.py that is likely to work, if so tell

I am using uv python for package mgmt.
Had to copy the contents of "/home/ujjwal/.local/share/uv/python/cpython-3.11.10-linux-x86_64-gnu/lib" folder to "venv/lib" folder. And it worked.
